# sitecore 6.6 lucene version incompatibility

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net

I'm upgrading to sitecore 6.6 rev 120918
I'm using lucene 2.9.4.1
When going to the console  index manager > choosing an index and then browse documents I get the error: Could not load file or assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.3.1.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
My understanding is that is a deprecated version,  any insights on how can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I presume you used the [Index Viewer](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Index_Viewer.aspx) from Sitecore Marketplace?

You need to make sure you are running the latest version (1.2) and the download the IndexViewer DLL which was built for Sitecore 6.6/Lucene 2.9.4.1

Basically download this DLL, rename to IndexViewer.dll and replace the existing dll of same name in your /bin directory.

https://github.com/JimmieOverby/IndexViewer/blob/master/IndexViewer.Sitecore66.dll

Comment: No problem, had the same issue upgrading up a project recently so knew exactly what the issue was :)

Comment: I can't download it... is there another place it's easily available? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @jammykam , I can't download it... is there another place it's easily available? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Iucounu When you get to the GitHub page click on "View Raw" or the "Raw" button to download the dll

Comment: @jammykam I replaced with the 6.6 IndexViewer.dll, but the 2.3.1.3 error still happens--but only upon trying to log in to the desktop. Ugh

Comment: @Iucounu Are you sure you replaced it in the correct location? i.e. make sure it is the `/bin` directory of your deployed CMS environment

Comment: @jammykam Yes, unfortunately. :|

Comment: @Iucounu Can't think of what else it could be. Make sure some other code is not referencing Lucene somewhere in your project, you could also try the assembly binding mentioned by Richard Seal

Comment: @jammykam Thank you. I never got binding failure logging working before but will try that. I checked the solution before to make sure no projects were referencing the old 2.3.1.3 version but will recheck. The assembly binding below simply doesn't work to solve this problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @jammykam The culprit has turned out to be the Sitecore WeBlog module, version 2.2. I am getting ready to investigate what's necessary to fix that problem. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: It turns out that there's a WeBlog module version 2.3 for Sitecore 6.6 and above, but I can't install it because the Sitecore desktop crashes due to the WeBlog module 2.2 pointing to Lucene.NET 2.3.1.3 . At this point I feel that the fragility of the Sitecore administrative desktop is a major drawback of the product.

Comment: I replaced the WeBlog .dll with the version 2.3 one, then was able to get the Sitecore 6.6 desktop to come up and do a proper package installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the 2.9.4 binary referenced in your project you will need to add a binding redirect to the web.config.

Something like this:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Lucene.Net" publicKeyToken="85089178b9ac3181" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.9.4.1" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assembleyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: The binary reference in the web.config was ok, the indexviewer dll was internally referencing the wrong lucene version.